# Passing Hashtable into method as a parameter throw null pointer exeception

Tags: java, parameters, hashtable, parameter-passing

I am trying pass a `Hashtable` as parameter into a method which itself passes that same table into another method:

```
     public class Recruiter {
               private WebDriver driver;
               private DataEntry d;
               private String password;

               public Recruiter(WebDriver driver){
               this.driver = driver;
               }

              public void createRecruiter(Hashtable<String, String> vars, String     preferences[]){       
               d.enterText(vars);
               driver.findElement(By.id("SAVE")).click();
        }

        Main:

                  Hashtable<String, String> vars = new   Hashtable<String, String>();

                       vars.put("DOB","02 Mar 1983");
                       vars.put("SURNAME","Release");
                       vars.put("FIRSTNAME","David");
                        vars.put("COMPANYNAME","Test Inc");


                   Recruiter recruiter = new Recruiter(driver);
                       recruiter.createRecruiter(vars, preferences);
```

However I keep getting a null pointer exception at: `d.enterText(vars);` what is the proper way to pass a `Hashtable` as a method parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just initialize `DataEntry d` before you use it. Something like:

```
d = new DataEntry();
```

inside the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see where you're initializing `d`. That's causing the NPE, not `vars`. That being said, `d` should be initialized in the constructor of `Recruiter`.